# C program returning incorrect double value

Tags: c, gcc, double

Code:

```cpp
int main(){
    double x = 10;
    double Fahrenheit = (x * (9/5)) + 32;
    double Celsius = (5 / 9) * (x - 32);

    printf("%lf\n", Fahrenheit);
    printf("%lf\n", Celsius);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
42.000000
-0.000000
```

I have tried re-arranging the formulas, I have also tried using functions but I can't seem to figure out why the ouput is incorrect.

For reference the expected output:

```
50.00000
-12.22222
```

---

re-arranging to:

```cpp
    double Fahrenheit = (x * 9 / 5) + 32;
    double Celsius = (x - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

worked!

but so did adding a .0 to all int numbers

Comment: `9/5 == 1` because it uses integer division.

Comment: " (9/5)" is integer division and is equal to 1. Try 9.0/5 instead. Similar for 5.0/9.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have worked. I didn't realise it would default to integer division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are performing the computation as ints (9/5) == 1 when (9.0 / 5.0) == 1.8.
Add .0 to all your numbers and you'll be fine

Comment: That has worked thank you!